# Open another panel inside another panel after pressing button

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, action, panel

I have been getting an error saying that i didn't add some methods(the action performed) but i already did. I'm having trouble opening the panel2.

```
public class panel1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener(){
    private panel2 p2=new panel2();
    private JButton button;

    public panel1(){
    button=new JButton("open panel2");
    add(button,BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            add(p2);

        }

    });

  }
```

}

Comment: panel1 needs to implement the actionPerformed method as described by the ActionListener interface

Comment: but isnt that already the one with the  @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            add(p2);

        }  ? Im sorry im new at programming

Comment: No, that's the anonymous classes implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can check the below code for replacing jpanel without switching jframe.  



contentPanel.removeAll();
        contentPanel.repaint();
        contentPanel.revalidate();
        contentPanel.add(//add your panel here);
        contentPanel.repaint();
        contentPanel.revalidate();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider these changes:

```
public class panel1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener(){
    private panel2 p2=new panel2();
    private JButton button;

    public panel1(){
    button=new JButton("open panel2");
    add(button,BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            //Add readability: Where to add?
            panel1.this.add(p2);
        }

    });

  }

  //THIS HERE makes your panel1 implment ActionListener
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

  }
}
```

Please also note commom Java naming conventions - Class names should start with uppercase letter (`Panel1 extends JPanel`)

Comment: Thanks! that removes the error. Although it still does not open the second panel..

Comment: Maybe you shoud add (panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER) or something?